# HDf5 Data Dimenssion change from (512,1080) to (512,1080,1)

Tags: python, python-3.x, hdf5

Hello i have a question about hdf5 . i have a data with dimension like (512,1080) but i need to convert it into (512,1080,1) ,1 represent the channel color how can i do that ? after convert this .it should be in same format like hdf5 not in numpy array

Comment: what have you tried yet? what isn't working?

Comment: i tried to find reshape function in hdf5 but i didnt get any function like this

Answer (score 0):

You could redimension your dataset (from `512x1080` to `512x1080x1`) with [HDFql](http://www.hdfql.com) as follows (assume that the dataset is named `dset` of 32 bit integer data type, and it is stored in an HDF5 file named `test.h5`):

```
import HDFql

HDFql.execute("USE FILE test.h5")  # open file "test.h5"

HDFql.execute("SELECT FROM dset")  # read data from dataset "dset" into HDFql cursor

HDFql.execute("CREATE TRUNCATE DATASET dset AS INT(512, 1080, 1)")  # re-create dataset "dset" with dimensions 512x1080x1

HDFql.execute("INSERT INTO dset")  # write data from HDFql cursor into dataset "dset"
```